# Parse.com Crash Reporting with Hybrid App

Tags: javascript, cordova, parse-platform, crash-reports

I developed a hybrid app with Cordova (currently iOS and Android).
As Backend I use parse.com. In my App I use the Javasript SDK from Parse.
Now I discovered that there is pretty good Crash Reporting offered by Parse and I am looking how I can best use this.
Is it possible to make Crash Reporting working through Javascript SDK? Or do I have to add iOS SDK to iOS and Android SDK to Android only for Crash Reporting? 
If only last thing works: does it not affect Javascript SDK and e.g. iOS SDK in the same Project?
Thanks for support!

Comment: you can create a plugin or you can use JS Sdk itself..http://phonegap.com/uploads/presentation/PhoneGapParse/preso/short.html#/21

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: No Error. Just wanted to know how to implement best.
How can I use it with JS SDK? Didn't find any solution, therefore I opened a new question.

Comment: http://phonegap.com/uploads/presentation/PhoneGapParse/preso/short.html#/21

Comment: I already clicked through this Presentation. But where does it tell anything about Crash Reporting with Javascript SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing as sunsetting parse.com